# Remove duplicate entries with Xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml data.

```
<product ID="2300">
<name>title</name>
<price currency="EUR">174.00</price>
</product>

<product ID="2300">
<name>title</name>
<price currency="EUR">164.00</price>
</product>
```

The only difference between these two is only the price. I just want to remove the duplicate rows. I have already tried with the following code.

```
/product[not(@ID=preceding-sibling::product/@ID)]/@ID
```

and

```
/product[not(@ID=preceding::product/@ID)]/@ID
```

But i get an error with no matching expressions found. I do not have any experience with xpath.

can somebody help me with this please...

**UPDATE**
I have included a part of the original xml tree and some screendumps (links only) what i see in the first steps of the wpallimport plugin.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated on 07/15/16 at 15:24:54  -->
<products>
<product ID="2300">
<name></name>
<price currency="EUR">174.00</price>
<URL></URL>
<images>
<image></image>
</images>
<description></description>
<categories/>
<properties>
<property name="priority">
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property name="accommodationName">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="city">
<value>City</value>
</property>
<property name="region">
<value>Region</value>
</property>
<property name="country">
<value>Country</value>
</property>
<property name="origin">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="transportType">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="departureDate">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="duration">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="minPersons">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="boardType">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="stars">
<value></value>
</property>
<property name="accommodationType">
<value></value>
</property>
</properties>
<variations/>
</product>
```

[Screendump1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJK6j.jpg)

[Screendump2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjwo8.jpg)

Comment: The XML you show is not well-formed: there is no containing wrapper element. If there is a wrapper element `products`, then your path should change to `/products/product[....]`. Apart from that, your XPath expressions look fine to me.

Comment: Thank you! You are right about the wrap. Check my other answer below!

Comment: Clearly we need to know the XDM tree that we are querying. From your description, given that we don't know the wpallimport plugin, we don't know whether the product elements are siblings and we don't know whether they are part of a tree rooted at a document node; without understanding the input, we can't really devise a suitable path expression.

Comment: The original post has an update. I hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: The screen dumps don't explain to me why the suggested path expressions don't work, so there's obviously something going on behind the scenes that's not clear to me at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
//product[following-sibling::product/@ID = @ID]
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Unfortunately this one doesn't do the job either. Maybe i should have given more details.  I am importing this feed into WooCommerce (Wordpress) with a plugin called wpallimport. 
I dont know if you are familiar with this plugin.

The only path visible is "/product". The original XML is well-formed and does have a wrapper named 'products'. The wrapper 'products' isn't visible because this plugin handles the feed with individual records. 
But only in the first step i have to filter the XML with Xpath.

I hope you have another suggestion.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ, please use `[edit]` to make "edit" a helpful link for the author.  You can also emphasise "how" and "why": `Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.`